# Calculate percent NA by ID variable in R

Tags: r, na, missing-data

Title is self-explanatory. Looking to calculate percent NA by ID group in R. There are lots of posts on calculating NA by variable column but almost nothing on doing it by row groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple columns, after grouping by 'ID', use `summarise_at` to loop over the columns, create a logical vector with `is.na`, get the `mean`, and multiply by 100

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ 100 *mean(is.na(.)))
```

---

If we want to get the percentage across all other variables,

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Perc = 100 * mean(is.na(value)))
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, FUN = function(x) 100 * mean(is.na(x)), na.action = na.pass)
```

Or to get the percentage across, then `unlist`, the other columns, create a `table`  with the logical vector and the 'ID' column, and use `prop.table` to get the percentage

```
prop.table(table(cbind(ID = df1$ID, 
        value = is.na(unlist(df1[setdiff(names(df1), "ID")]))))
```

Comment: I got this error: Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020  Do you have a data.frame or matrix

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020  It may be better if you can update your post with the `dput` of a small example data

Comment: Dataframe... the second command worked but what if I wanted to see the aggregate across all variables and not percentages by individual variables

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020  Updated the post

Comment: Beautiful! Updated post works like a dream! Thanks again!